# Earn badge for referencing other SO posts on your answers

Tags: discussion, badge-request

I think this suggestion comes with the question `how important are references` on SO.

Citing other member’s work is important to make clear that you read/understood another coder’s work and it also strengthens your own answer.

Since this is a task that demands time searching on SO, I think adding a badge for this kind of behavior is something we should consider.

I don't know what would be the most appropriate type of badge, but it will certainly have to do with the number of references the user made on all his answers. Maybe we could count only the answers that got voted up or something like that.

Comment: Maybe we should add a badge for proper use of formatting tools too.

Answer (score 6):

I think if my answer is a link to another answer I should get a

> [should-have-closed-as-dupe-but-decided-to-rep-whore]

badge.

Comment: Not if you add new valid information to it.

Comment: Not all links are duplicates. Sometimes you use it to illustrate a minor point in your own answer - that's where a badge would be appropriate. Gotta admit it would be hard for the bots to tell the difference.